# What does this "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9810) error in__connection__block_invoke_2:Connection interupted" means?

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling

When my iphone get locked, why I'm getting this error in Objective c and functionality not work.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for these error code:

```
errSSLInternal              = -9810,    /* Internal error */
```

Check error codes here:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55179.13/libsecurity_ssl/Security/SecureTransport.h

If your application attempts to connect to any HTTP server that doesn’t support the latest SSL technology (TLSv1.2), your connections will fail with an error like that.

If you trying to connect to a host (www.example.com) that only has TLS 1.0.

Then you have to set following keys into your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**OR** update HTTP server to latest TLS version.

Hope this will help:)

Source: https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: i already try  this ,but not working :(,please suggest another solution